# Keeping Specific Rows in Excel According to a Guide

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a sheet like this:

```
     A           B           C                       D
Employee ID   Last Name  First Name   Employees Working on Project A
10001           aaa        bbb                     10004
10002           mmm        nnn                     10006
10003           yyy        zzz                     10009
10004           uuu        xxx                     10010
10005           fff        ggg
10007           kkk        hhh
10009           rrr        ppp
```

I want to isolate all employees working on Project A and delete the rest of the rows. However, of those isolated IDs, I would like to keep rows B and C. Any idea how I do this without having to do it manually?

Comment: What are the criteria for keeping these rows? What have you tried? What is the context? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I thought I made that quite clear. It's pretty simple, really.

Comment: We can't make any assumptions.  For example, are the rows you want to keep always just 'B and C', or do they vary?

Answer (score 1):

I would insert a column after column C
A formula like

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$5,0))
```

will return True if working on Project A, false otherwise

You can then filter or sort on that column